# how to get predicted intervals? code no giving me those values

Tags: confidence-interval, cross-validation, linear-model, prediction-interval, ggplot2

I am doing a cross validation in a training data and I am getting my predicted values with my test data. I want to do a plot with predicted versus observed with the predicted intervals but my code is not working. I get the predicted values but no the values for the interval. Also the error I get when I try to do the plot is:

> "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'lwr' not found".

```
set.seed(400)
train.control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 14, repeats = 50)

model <- train(y ~., data = train, method = "lm", trControl = train.control)

predictions <- predict(model, test, interval = 'confidence')

all_data <- cbind(test, predictions)

ggplot(all_data, aes(x, y)) +  geom_point() + stat_smooth(method = lm) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = lwr), col = "coral2", linetype = "dashed") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = upr), col = "coral2", linetype = "dashed")
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call on the lm object inside caret to calculate confidence, the warning basically tells you it's not found in the input data.frame, below I use BostonHousing, as an example:

```
library(caret)
library(ggplot2)
library(mlbench)
data(BostonHousing)
set.seed(400)

idx = sample(nrow(BostonHousing),400)
train = BostonHousing[idx,-4]
test = BostonHousing[-idx,-4]
train.control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 3)
model <- train(medv ~., data = train, method = "lm", trControl = train.control)
predictions <-predict(model$finalModel, test,interval="confidence")
all_data <- cbind(test, predictions)

ggplot(all_data, aes(x=fit, y=medv)) +  geom_point() + stat_smooth(method = lm) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = lwr), col = "coral2", linetype = "dashed") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = upr), col = "coral2", linetype = "dashed")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much @StupidWolf it works!!!

Comment: I am having another problem. The confidence interval from my predictions do not match the ones showing by ggplot. Any idea why?

Comment: they are two very different things. one is the standard error of the fit coming from your model. https://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/18/help-and-how-to/modeling-statistics/using-fitted-models/supporting-topics/prediction/what-is-the-standard-error-of-the-fits/

Comment: the one you in ggplot, is the standard error of regression between fitted and predicted, where you fit another linear model. You don't usually compare like that.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I was trying to do  graph that I saw in a paper and it had it that way but it is incorrect.